# Missing AdMobDelegateProtocol.h when building with AdWhirl on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, admob, adwhirl

I downloaded the latest AdWhirl and AdMob SDKs a few days ago, followed the iPhone installation instructions for both and ran into this error while trying to build:

```
AdMobDelegateProtocol.h: No such file or directory in AdWhirl/adapters/AdWhirlAdapterAdmob.h
```

I can't find that file anywhere and the AdMob SDK website makes no mention of it. Where can I get this file? Is the latest version of AdMob no longer compatible with AdWhirl?

Answer (score 0):

Having similar problem.
Upgrading an old app. Working with older sdk's of adwhirl and admob.

Downloaded latet adwhirl sdk
Downloaded admob sdk.

Same issue as you are having.

Has admob been updated and lost compatibility with adwhirl sdk suddenly?

AdMobDelegateProtocol.h No such file or directory. 
Seems to me that this header file used by adwhirl is no longer part of admob sdk download.

Found the answer here. Admob has been updated, adwhirl has not yet.
http://groups.google.com/group/adwhirl-users/browse_thread/thread/e0baf3c472a3420f

Need to find those older admob sdk's.

Comment: Any luck finding an older Admob SDK? I'm stuck on this too.